# Unable to make footer stick to bottom

Tags: html, css

I was designing an basic template for my new script but I am unable to make footer to be at bottom.

demo [here](http://jsbin.com/fepawaxa/2)

I tried

```
position: relative;bottom: 15px;
```

but its not working the footer is placed in nearby middle of the page please help me resolving this problem.
You can edit my template or view the source [here](http://jsbin.com/fepawaxa/2/edit).

Comment: Change position to absolute and bottom:0px;

Comment: making position absolute makes it overlap with content when opend in small devices ,I want to make my page responsive.

Comment: give the element before a padding-bottom to make space for the absolutly positioned footer.

Comment: Please update my fiddle with appropriate solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warp Up The content in an `div`

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div class="page-wrap">

    Content..

    </div>

    <footer>
        Footer Content..
    </footer>

</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}
body,html{
    height: 100%;
}
.page-wrap{
    min-height: 90%;/* Adjust This Value According to your Footer .*/
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want the footer to stay at the bottom even if the page requires scrolling, you can use

```
postion: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
```

This will make it stick to the bottom left corner.

EDIT: If you want it to be slightly off the bottom just change the value of 'bottom' to the appropriate px or percent.

EDIT (again): To avoid overlap with content you can do something along these lines.

HTML:

```
<div id='Content'></div>
<div id='Footer'></div>
```

CSS:

```
#Content
{
    position: relative;
    height: calc( 100% - 100px );
    height: -webkit-calc( 100% - 100px );
    height: -moz-calc( 100% - 100px );
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

#Footer
{
    position:fixed;
    height: 100px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: making position absolute makes it overlap with content when opend in small devices ,I want to make my page responsive.

Comment: If you want to make the page responsive you can set use something along these lines to ensure your content doesn't get overlayed by the footer.

Comment: This will allow for scrolling vertically if the content overflows the allocated space. But will leave the content un-overlapped by the footer and will allow the footer to stick to the bottom left.

Answer (score 3):

optionally you need replace `position:relative;` in `position: absolute; bottom: 0;`
it pushes the footer to the bottom of the screen

or a standart solution
 **HTML**

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="main" class="clearfix">

    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* { margin:0; padding:0; } 
html, body, #wrap { height: 100%; }
body > #wrap {height: auto; min-height: 100%;}
#main { padding-bottom: 150px; }  /* must be same height as the footer */
#footer { 
        position: relative;
    margin-top: -150px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 150px;
    clear:both;} 
/* CLEAR FIX*/
.clearfix:after {content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;}
.clearfix {display: inline-block;}
/* Hides from IE-mac \*/
* html .clearfix { height: 1%;}
.clearfix {display: block;}
/* End hide from IE-mac */
```

Comment: making position absolute makes it overlap with content when opend in small devices ,I want to make my page responsive.

Comment: then you need to add to the body height of 100%

Answer (score 2):

This is because your footer is placed at the bottom of the  content. You'll need

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
```

You may also need something similar on the body element. Also you will need to use `position: absolute; bottom: 0` if you want it to show up at the bottom of the page and not 15px above where it would normally be.

Answer (score 1):

i already proved in my page and it works fine

in your css put the code above

```
#footer {
    clear: both;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    text-align: right;

    position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
   background:#6cf;
}
```

and in your page you only call the footer style

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="header"></div>
   <div id="body"></div>
   <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

and there you are! you have your footer...i hope i helped you

Answer (score 0):

There is a great sticky footer I use from [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/)

I have gone ahead and adapted it for you.

[Jsbin link](http://jsbin.com/fepawaxa/9/edit)

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.4.2/pure-min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div style="position: relative;text-align: right;right: 50px; top: 15px;">
        <a class="pure-button pure-button-primary" href="?help">Help</a>
    </div>
    <div class="header">
        <h1>Template</h1>
        <h2>basic page.</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="content">

    <h2 class="content-subhead">Enter Link</h2>

    <form class="pure-form pure-form-aligned" action="index.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>To bo bla bla bla Please Enter <code>Link</code> Below.</legend>
        <div class="pure-control-group">
            <label>Link</label>
            <input name="link" type="text" class="pure-input-2-3" placeholder="link" value="" required>
        </div>

        <div class="pure-controls">
            <label class="pure-checkbox">
                <input name="start" type="checkbox"> Start Downloading Instantly.
            </label>
            <button type="submit" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">Generate</button>
        </div>
    <p>To get Help on Using this click <a class="link" href="?help">here</a>. </p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
<footer class="site-footer">
<p>Script By <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;color:inherit;">Lorem ipsum</a>.</p>
<p>&copy; 2014 . All rights reserved.</p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
background: #FFF;
}

.header {
       font-family: "omnes-pro", sans-serif;

       padding: 1em;
       text-align: center;
       border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
       background: #fff;
  }
  .header h1 {
      font-size: 300%;
      font-weight: 100;
      margin: 0;
      color: #4B4B4B;
  }
   .header h2 {
      font-size: 125%;
      font-weight: 100;
      line-height: 1.5;
      margin: 0;
      color: #666;
  }
  .content {

       margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 768px;
  min-height: 80%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -142px;
  }

   .content:after {
   content:"";
  display: block;
  }

  .content .content-subhead {
      font-weight: 300;
      color: #888;

  }

  .link {
  display: inline-block;

  padding-left: 6px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #6AB3EC;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
  }

  .link:hover {
      color: #3C9CE7;
  }
  .link:before {
      content: "\25BA";
      font-size: 80%;
      display: inline-block;
      padding-right: 3px;
      pointer-events: none;
  }

  .link:hover:before {
      color: #F2BF97;
  }


 .site-footer, .content:after {
  /* .push must be the same height as footer */
  height: 142px;
  width: 300px; margin: 0 auto;

 }

.site-footer { text-align: center;}
```

Comment: No worries, make sure you tweak it and clean it up a little. The height of `.site-footer, .content:after` and the negative margin of `.content` will need to be changed and the height of `.content` will probably be `100%`. Just experiment :)

Comment: you have added `margin-bottom: -142px;` in `.content` but i fear this will be a page generated by php and the contents will change accordingly will the css work ?

Comment: Is the footer content going to be changed much? If it is, then just make sure the height of the footer is enough to cover any changes. The negative margin needs to be the same value as the height, but itself will provide no problems. If the footer wont change, then you will have no problems at all :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want your footer to be sticky make the footers position fixed

```
position:fixed;
```

If you want it to be at the bottom of the page initially instead of position relative make it absolute

```
position:absolute;
```

also you might want to give your body and html 100% height.